# List all matched instances of a value

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, match

I am trying to build an order guide and want everything I order from one vendor put onto a separate sheet.

Sometimes I bring on new products from vendors and need the list to automatically update as well.

Currently my formula looks like this:

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX('Order Guide'!A1:B240,SMALL(IF('Order Guide'!B1:B240=$A$1,ROW('Order Guide'!B1:B240)),ROW('Order Guide'!1:1)),2)),"",INDEX('Order Guide'!B1:B240,SMALL(IF('Order Guide'!B1:B240=$A$1,ROW('Order Guide'!B1:B240)),ROW('Order Guide'!1:1)),2))
```

But it isn't working. Where am I messing up?

Listed here is my current spreadsheet: 
[image: Photo of current spread sheet]

Basically, I want everything in `Column B` that says **National** to go to a separate sheet.

Comment: So I'm not sure what you mean by *"...it isn't working,"* but I see *many* (potential) basic issues with your formula. First, the range `A1:B240` is relative, not absolute, so as the formula is copied down each row, that range moves as well (e.g. becomes `A2:B241`, etc.). Secondly, you're always comparing to `$A$1`, but we don't know what's in `$A$1` as it seems to be on a separate sheet. Also, your second `INDEX` function has a one-column **array** argument, but you're asking it to return column 2 of the **array**, which is non-existent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever I want certain records from a list to appear in a different place, I turn my source data into an Excel Table, and make a PivotTable out of it, and then filter that PivotTable to show just the items I'm interested in.

No formulas, and as soon as you refresh the PivotTable it will automatically pick up any changes to your source data. Unlike formulas, which can be overwhelmingly complex to pick apart, and rely on you remembering to drag the formula down the page in order to ensure you capture any new data.